# O que significa til antes do nome de uma Classe no corpo da classe

Tags: c#

Eu realmente fico sem entender certas coisas. Por exemplo, o que significa isso:

```
**~TesteGeral();**

public class TesteGeral : IDisposable
{
   public TesteGeral(){string teste, string user }
   ~TesteGeral();
   //métodos não implementados aqui(não entendi, parece uma interface)
}
```